# Commas in SVG path descriptions

Tags: svg

When describing paths in SVG, online examples often separate values with commas, while others don't.

[The paths tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) from the Mozilla Developer Network SVG Tutorial uses both notations to describe arcs:

```
A 30 50 0 0 1 162.55 162.45
```

and

```
A 45 45, 0, 0, 0, 125 125
```

[Elsewhere](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/path-element.html#arcs), I have also seen:

```
A30,50 0 0,1 100,100
```

### When and where do SVG path descriptions need commas?

Answer (score 28):

[Commas are mostly optional](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataBNF) and whitespace is also mostly optional. You need one or the other in some cases to say when something ends and the next thing begins i.e. so that 1,1 or 1 1 is not parsed as 11.

You can put a single comma between any two numbers so `A, 30 50 0 0 1 162.55 162.45` is invalid as is `A 30,, 50 0 0 1 162.55 162.45`

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more, I am also confused with the Arc command why mdn has between the x and y coordinates a comma. They also have multiple commas and the w3c says that spaces should suffice

Answer (score 12):

The [W3C SVG Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html) states that:

> Superfluous white space and separators such as commas can be eliminated (e.g., "M 100 100 L 200 200" contains unnecessary spaces and could be expressed more compactly as "M100 100L200 200").